# Self-modifying code in Ruby reloaded

Tags: ruby, closures, block, self-modifying

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658230), let me be more precise and less obfuscative about what exactly I want. I wrote a chemical package, where I made a decision that the names of all the chemicals and reactions will be capitalized, such as 'ATP', 'Adenosine', 'DeoxyCytidine' etc. That allowed me to write eg:

```
ATP = ChemicalSpecies.new initial_concentration: 225.0     # in micromolars
GDP = ChemicalSpecies.new initial_concentration: 75.0      # in micromolars
```

Now if ATP is used to phosphorylate GDP, using enzyme NDPK with catalytic constant

```
NDPK_constant = 0.6
```

, this I want to be written as:

```
ChemicalReaction.new name: ATP_GDP_phosphate_exchange,
                     rate: lambda { ATP * GDP * NDPK_constant }
```

I could just write:

```
ChemicalReaction.new name: ATP_GDP_phosphate_exchange,
                     reactants: [ ATP, GDP ],
                     rate: lambda { |reactant_1, reactant_2| reactant_1 * reactant_2 * NDPK_constant }
```

But it seems too wet to me. See how `reactant_1`, `reactant_2` repeqt twice, while `ATP`, `GDP` being in mind. The easy solution would be:

```
ChemicalReaction.new name: ATP_GDP_phosphate_exchange,
                     rate: lambda { _ATP * _GDP * NDPK_constant }
```

And `instance_eval` the rate-finding block in the context that defines `_ATP` and `_GDP` as concentrations of `ATP`, `GDP`. This is very very close, but not *exactly* the thing I want, and that pisses the heaven out of me. I could even use `RubyVM` to find, which chemicals are used inside the block, consider eg.

```
require 'ap' # (awesome_print, like pretty_print but fancier, install if you don't have)
ap RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disassemble( lambda { _ATP * _GDP * NDPK_constant } ).split( "\n" )
#=> [ 0] "== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:block in irb_binding@(irb)>=====",
    [ 1] "== catch table",
    [ 2] "| catch type: redo   st: 0000 ed: 0027 sp: 0000 cont: 0000",
    [ 3] "| catch type: next   st: 0000 ed: 0027 sp: 0000 cont: 0027",
    [ 4] "|------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    [ 5] "0000 trace            1                                               (  22)",
    [ 6] "0002 putself          ",
    [ 7] "0003 send             :_ATP, 0, nil, 24, <ic:0>",
    [ 8] "0009 putself          ",
    [ 9] "0010 send             :_GDP, 0, nil, 24, <ic:1>",
    [10] "0016 opt_mult         <ic:5>",
    [11] "0018 getinlinecache   25, <ic:3>",
    [12] "0021 getconstant      :NDPK_constant",
    [13] "0023 setinlinecache   <ic:3>",
    [14] "0025 opt_mult         <ic:6>",
    [15] "0027 leave
```

By parsing this, one learns what names are inside: `_ATP` and `_GDP`. But like I said, out of stubbornness, I find `_ATP`, `_GDP` ugly. I want to say just `ATP`, `GDP`, or perhaps `[ATP]`, `[GDP]`, because chemists use brackets for concentrations. I know that this is what Yusuke Endoh calls constrained coding. My question is, can either of these two desirable syntaxes be beaten? For example, having a closure `lambda { ATP * GDP * NDPK_constant }`, disassembling it gives:

```
ap RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disassemble( lambda { ATP * GDP * NDPK_constant } ).split( "\n" )
#=> [ 0] "== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:block in irb_binding@(irb)>=====",
    [ 1] "== catch table",
    [ 2] "| catch type: redo   st: 0000 ed: 0027 sp: 0000 cont: 0000",
    [ 3] "| catch type: next   st: 0000 ed: 0027 sp: 0000 cont: 0027",
    [ 4] "|------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    [ 5] "0000 trace            1                                               (  23)",
    [ 6] "0002 getinlinecache   9, <ic:0>",
    [ 7] "0005 getconstant      :ATP",
    [ 8] "0007 setinlinecache   <ic:0>",
    [ 9] "0009 getinlinecache   16, <ic:1>",
    [10] "0012 getconstant      :GDP",
    [11] "0014 setinlinecache   <ic:1>",
    [12] "0016 opt_mult         <ic:5>",
    [13] "0018 getinlinecache   25, <ic:3>",
    [14] "0021 getconstant      :NDPK_constant",
    [15] "0023 setinlinecache   <ic:3>",
    [16] "0025 opt_mult         <ic:6>",
    [17] "0027 leave
```

One sees that `getconstant` appeared at lines 7, 10 for `:ATP`, `:GDP`. Outside the block, `ATP` and `GDP` constants contain `ChemicalSpecies` instances, but inside the block, I want them to refer to ATP and GDP *concentrations*. I didn't find any way to evaluate the block in an evironment where the constants themselves have different meanings (that is, unless I want to temporarily rewrite the constants at runtime using dirty tricks, which is what I don't want). What I crave for is to be able to replace this RubyVM code `getconstant :ATP` instruction by eg. `send  :_ATP, 0, nil, 24, <ic:0>`, and then eg. `instance_eval` this closure in an evironment where `_ATP` means `ATP.concentration`... I know I'm asking difficult questions, sorry again...

As for the second option `[ATP]`, `[GDP]`, that one would require activating some sort of new array creation hook inside the block only, so that if there is just one element, that is a `ChemicalSpecies`, its concentration would be returned instead of an array object. I think this is equally difficult, if not impossible task.

Comment: Please remove all the chemistry talk and generalize. We might all sound like we're speaking martian to the outside world, but this is greek to me. Also, disassembly is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: This just confirms to me you are trying to bend a hammer into a fork (or insert other clever saying). If your users are the primary concern then to hell with whatever some programming philosopher says :) Code for the users as prime directive number 1. There is no way you can make [ATP] behave nicely without a dung heap of ugly spaghetti code that nobody will be able to decipher and maintain. And not only that but it will be brittle code dependant on Ruby internals. If you write your own domain-language you will have ultimate control and be a much happier coder in the end (users happier too).

Comment: Also if you see the [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14658827/823617). You might even be able to get around the whole thing without building a parser. Just some simple string replacement and `eval` could even do the trick. I.e. replace `[ATP]` with `ATP.concetration` and `eval` the whole thing.

Comment: Also, remember that lambdas also capture constants. A lambda defined in a context where ATP and GDP are available is a lambda in which they are accessible.

Comment: @Linuxios: Yes, and they capture constants in a very constant way, that no instance_eval can deal with, I learned.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone, and especially to Casper. To summarize, I was pointed towards [Sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify) / [RubyParser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser), and told to rape not Ruby code. Sourcify / RubyParser is the exact answer I wanted, but Casper only mentioned them in comments. Whatever - heaven take the reputation. Since I posted, a new idea paid me a visit - fake Unicode brackets:

```
ChemicalSpecies = Struct.new :concentration
ATP, GDP = ChemicalSpecies[ 225.0 ], ChemicalSpecies[ 75.0 ]
class << ( ChemicalSystem = Object.new )
  def ⁅ATP⁆; ATP.concentration end
  def ⁅GDP⁆; GDP.concentration end
end
rate = lambda { ⁅ATP⁆ + ⁅GDP⁆ * 0.6 }
ChemicalSystem.instance_exec &rate
#=> 10125.0
```

Fake brackets `⁅ATP⁆` look better than the hated plain solution `_ATP`. There are few more of the better looking options, such as full-width brackets `［ATP］`, but the concern is not only how to type them, but also how to not have the user confuse them with vanillas. I've scoured whole Unicode, and the only other option I hated not was `｢ATP`. Of course, this has nothing to do with self-modifying code; real answer was in Casper's comments.